# Function similar to .endsWith in Java in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have some strings in my array which can be .html or .txt files. In Java we can use `.endsWith("String")` to check whether a string ends with another string How can we achieve the same thing in Objective-C?

eg: I want to check whether this string ends with .html or .txt.

Comment: If you are specifically checking for file extensions, then use `- pathExtension`. If not, then use `rangeOfString:`.

Comment: Please take a moment to scan the documentation for `NSString`. You'll find your answer very quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)hasSuffix:(NSString *)aString
```

Comment: @user2758888 .... and if is a path, then this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 9):

So it looks like the strings are filenames, so you can use [`[NSString pathExtension]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/pathExtension):

```
NSString *extension = [filename pathExtension];
if ([extension isEqualToString:@"html"]) {
    // it's .html
} else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"txt"]) {
    // it's .txt
} else {
    // it's neither .html nor .txt
}
```